# Rails sql includes table from another base and add where condition on it?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, multi-database, multi-database-connections

I have a specific database (called account_base) for my account :

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  establish_connection :account_base
  
  ...
end
```

I have user from app rails database :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

When I try `User.first.account` this work fine.

Now I want get all users with account => state == Account::STATE_ACTIVED, I try :

```
User.includes(:account).where('accounts.state' => Account::STATE_ACTIVED)
```

but I have this error :

> Mysql2::Error: Table 'RAILS_DATABASE_NAME.accounts' doesn't exist

I try with `where('account_base.accounts.state'` to specify the bd, but not works

Any idea ?

Comment: I am not sure it is possible if those are two separate database clusters, examples you provided will work for separate schemas in one cluster though

Comment: This would require the use of foreign data wrapper. Are you sure you really want to design it like this?

Comment: How do you design multi web site with only one account for each otherwise ?

Comment: @max maybe I can duplicate state in user main database, but I have to update in each database project the state if value is update in one of them, it's not realy good too... any idea?

Comment: Depends entirely on you requirements. You should probably look into the authentication as a service architecture which you can build with doorkeeper or use third party solutions such as auth0.